# Preserving type signature when returning a function that was supplied as a parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, functional-programming, typescript2.0

I have a function called `conditional` that takes in a boolean value and a function, and returns that function if the boolean value is true, or else, returns a dummy function.

```
function conditional(x, f) {
  if(x)
    return f
  else
    return () => {}
}
```

So, I can execute code like this:

```
let mySqrt = conditional(true, Math.sqrt)
let add = (x, y) => x + y
let myAdd = conditional(true, add)
```

However, when I add types to the conditional function, the type signature of the function supplied to the `conditional` function is lost. And this makes it possible to write code like `mySqrt("a")` without TypeScript complaining.

How do I add types to the conditional function such that the type of the resulting function is preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a generic type parameter to represent the type of the function:

```
function conditional<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(x: boolean, f: T): T {
    if (x)
        return f;
    else
        return (() => { }) as any; // we need an assertion here to make the empty function compatible with T
}

// Usage
let mySqrt = conditional(true, Math.sqrt); //mySqrt will be of type (x: number) => number
let add = (x: number, y: number) => x + y;
let myAdd = conditional(true, add); // myAdd will be of type (x: number, y: number) => number
```

Comment: While Tao's solution works, I find this solution more general and closer to what I intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of generics and method overload signatures.

```
function conditional<T extends Function>(x: true, f: T): T;
function conditional<T extends Function>(x: false, f: T): () => {};
function conditional<T extends Function>(x: boolean, f: T) {
  if(x)
    return f
  else
    return () => {}
}

let mySqrt = conditional(true, Math.sqrt)
mySqrt('a') // error
```

When providing overloaded method signatures the compiler will hide the actual, more flexible implementation.

Comment: While it's great to type the result differently on parameter constants, I think in this case the desired result is to be able to chose an implementation based on a parameter and have the rest of the code work seamlessly regardless of implementation. Your implementation would break client code based on the passed in constant, not sure that was the intent, but OP should weigh in

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir good point, I had a long night and didn't think too much about the possible use case. I also didn't see that you had already posted an answer before me...